# Change cell color if the two values of this cell have opposite signs in Pretty tables in Julia

Tags: datatables, julia, prettytable

How to change cell color if the two values of this cell have opposite signs in Pretty tables in Julia below is my code and the table is attached.

names = string.(-1/1:1/4:1/1)
pretty_table(AStrings , header = ([-1,-3/4, -1/2, -1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1]), row_names= names)

[image]

Comment: BTW try to make code in question runnable. Screenshots are not so helpful when trying to get the situation replicated.

Answer (score 3):

After digging through the docs:

```
using PrettyTables

# making some demo data
data = collect(zip(rand([-1.0,1.0],5,5),rand([-1.0,1.0],5,5)))
names = [-1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1]

# this is the Highlighter which makes text red when signs differ.
# signs differ if their product is negative.
hl = Highlighter((d,i,j)->d[i,j][1]*d[i,j][2] < 0, crayon"red")
```

Then the Highlighter is used as follows:

```
pretty_table(data ; header = names, row_names= names, highlighters=hl)
```

[image]

Well, colors don't go through in text, so put an image of result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, I got the following error ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::String, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::Union{StatsBase.PValue, StatsBase.TestStat}, ::Real) at C:\Users\Hind\.julia\packages\StatsBase\XgjIN\src\statmodels.jl:90
  isless(::AbstractString, ::AbstractString) at strings/basic.jl:344
  isless(::ReverseDiff.TrackedReal, ::Integer) at C:\Users\Hind\.julia\packages\ReverseDiff\5MMPp\src\derivatives\scalars.jl:42
  ... The AStrings =  fill("", 9, 9) is defined as this 
Can you help ?

Comment: The error is caused by trying to compare a string and a number. Some of your data is converted to strings perhaps using `string.(...)`. Try to make any conversions to strings as late as possible, just before printing, or not at all, since `pretty_print` converts to strings itself.
[in any case, it will be easier to find the problem with the actual code being run and not just the error]

Comment: In the question `AStrings` is the data to print. It seems to be already in string format, which is mostly useless for the Highlighter. If you have another variable with the raw data, it might be used inside the Highlighter, as some hack.

Comment: I see  I saved it as a string because I want to save the first number then "," then the second number. However, these numbers were saved in 2 vectors b4 that   c=  zeros(81)
 c2 = zeros(81). Now I should write hl = Highlighter((c,c2,i,j)->c,c2[i,j][1]* c,c2[i,j][2] < 0, crayon"red")
pretty_table(c,c2 , header = ([-1,-3/4, -1/2, -1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1]), row_names= names , highlighters=hl) or how ?

Comment: `hl = Highlighter((d,i,j)->c[i*9+j]*c2[i*9+j] < 0, crayon"red")` might do it. The parameters can't be changed (they are what `pretty_print` expects, but the function can access `c` and `c2`. I hope the index calculation is right (perhaps `i` and `j` need to be swapped).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is beyond what was asked by the OP, but hopefully would be informative. In addition to [Dan Getz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73772403/11747148), one can apply more than one rule for highlighting the values. For example, if you want to make pairs with positive value green besides the first rule, you can pass a tuple of `Highlighter` to the `highlighters` keyword argument.

I will use Dan's example to show you the results:

```
julia> hl = (
           Highlighter((d,i,j)->d[i,j][1]*d[i,j][2]<0, crayon"red"),
           Highlighter((d,i,j)->d[i,j][1]>0 && d[i,j][2]>0, crayon"green")
       )
```

The result of `pretty_table(data; header=names, row_names=names, highlighters=hl)` would be:

[image]